# How do I add a delay inside the next block of subscribe in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm subscribing to a service method and inside the next statement I'm displaying a toaster, reseting a form and navigating to another component but I'd like to add a delay before navigating to show the toaster to users in order for them to know what's going to happen next: navigating to another page.

```
this.auth.signup(body).subscribe({
  next: () => {
    this.toastr.success("Redirecting you to login.", 'Register successful!');
    this.signUpForm.reset();
    
    // Here I'd like to wait before navigating
    
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  },
  error: (err) => { this.toastr.error(err?.error.message, 'Oops!'); }
  });
```

I've tried different methods I found on the internet. From adding a delay using the 'rxjs/operators' package right before the navigation (inside next block) to using pipes and promises but nothing worked for me so far.

Comment: Personally, I would use the rxjs delay operator since it's already provided. In order to make it work, you need to restructured your code so that only the line after the delay is actually in the Subscribe call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward solution would be to just use the classic [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function and call your `this.router.navigate(['login']);` inside the function's callback. See this example with a delay of 2 seconds:

```
this.auth.signup(body).subscribe({
  next: () => {
    this.toastr.success("Redirecting you to login.", 'Register successful!');
    this.signUpForm.reset();
    
    // Wait before navigating
    setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate(['login']), 2000)    
  },
  error: (err) => { this.toastr.error(err?.error.message, 'Oops!'); }
});
```

I built a simplified version (with console outputs) of your code in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ktl6qq?file=index.ts). Click the button and monitor the console outputs - this should do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick. I was using Edge to keep my frontend running and for some reason it didn't register the wait but Chrome did. Will stick to Chrome for now :). Thanks again!